# How to post JSON on azure.websites

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, azure-storage

So, i have pretty specific question. I'm working on a college project with visual studio and we are building a website. Having in mind that running project locally is extremely slow my team and i decided to post it on azurewebsites.net. When we build solution everything works fine, but when project is published there is a problem with google maps, to be specific with saving markers made by user to database. I'm posting JSON data when user clicks on saveMarkers and it's working perfectly while debugging but not at all when running on server. Is this some kind of usual problem, and how to solve it?? I would be very very very thankful if someone who had similar experience says something :)

Comment: Any console errors in the browser?

Comment: Are you using API-Key for Google maps.

Comment: There are no errors, but i found out that it actually stores the markers but sets their latitude and longitude to 0, and that does not happen on local version, is it possible that the problem is in database couse i save decimal values like 11,1111, but maybe azure server don't recognize that. A made it to save like that couse when i run locally database doesn't recognize 11.111. And not forget to mention it's the same database that i use with my local version and my azrewebsites.net version.

Comment: And i'm not using API key for Google maps. Could this cause shuch problem? I mean what happens when i don't use API-key?

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't an obvious problem here but that's mostly because you haven't told is what *does* happen when its not working

Look in the developer console of your browser to see if it reports any errors.  Then turn on logging on Azure and see if any errors are caught server-side

Comment: There are no errors, but i found out that it actually stores the markers but sets their latitude and longitude to 0, and that does not happen on local version, is it possible that the problem is in database couse i save decimal values like 11,1111, but maybe azure server don't recognize that. A made it to save like that couse when i run locally database doesn't recognize 11.111.